# PHP date won't add

Tags: php, datetime

My problem is Enddate won't add to my database but the space and startdate adds just fine.

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $space=$_POST['space'];
    $startdate = date("Y-m-d");
    $enddate= "date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 7 days'))";
    
    $query="insert into reservation (Sublessee_space,Res_startdate,Res_enddate) values('$space','$startdate','$enddate')";
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($server);
    header('location:approve.php');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$enddate` is a string, not a date. Remove the `"` quotations around it so the PHP will execute.

From this:

```
$enddate= "date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 7 days'))";
```

To this:

```
$enddate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 7 days'));
```